# What is the syntax to pass a query in the ajax url using Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm opening a modal with ajax, but I'm having a problem because I need to access a url on my site that needs a query

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myBtn2').onclick = function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"{% url 'add_data' %}?filter=crew",
       type:'GET',
       success: function(data){
           $('#modal-content2').html(data);
       }
    });
}
</script>
```

I can't access url with the query, just the url alone. for example:

```
url:"{% url 'index' %}"
```

But if I put a query in the url it still doesn't work. I think the syntax is wrong and I can't figure out what it looks like.

```
url:"{% url 'add_dados' %}?filter=crew" --> doesn't work
```

Any suggests?

Comment: Check your dev console and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the querystring as dictionary when making an AJAX request:

```
document.getElementById('myBtn2').onclick = function(){
    $.ajax({
       url:"{% url 'add_data' %}",
       type:'GET',
       data: {
           filter: "crew"
       },
       success: function(data){
           $('#modal-content2').html(data);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did not work. "?" in URL acts as separator, it indicates end of URL resource path and start of query parameters. How can I pass these parameters to access the URL? I don't want to pass the data as if I were going to access it through a request. I just want to access the add_data url?filter=crew. This is important because the content of the page will depend on what is passed in these parameters in the URL.

Comment: @searcher__dm01: for a GET request the data is encoded in the querystring, so after the `?`. This is how data is passed in a GET request, and this is thus how AJAX encodes it: see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ , it says for the data parameter: *If the HTTP method is one that cannot have an entity body, **such as GET**, the data is **appended to the URL**.* and later *For example, `{ a: "bc", d: "e,f" }` is converted to the string `"a=bc&d=e%2Cf"`*